(Uncaught promise) Failed to fetch while POST'ing different json content
I am trying to GET user listings from a node.js server with the fetch API, by POST'ing the json {pageNumber,UsersPerPage}. For that I have two buttons, that each POST their own text contents as pageNumbers to the server, when clicked. However, after iterating the two buttons 6 times the fetch API somehow fails. It fails after I send 6 fetch requests -so when I iterate between the two buttons six times -and the error message "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch at HTMLDivElement." gets returned.
This is my frontend code:

side1.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    fetch('/api/users/stats/side1/post',{  
       method:'POST',
       headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},
       body:JSON.stringify({
        pageNum:side1.textContent,
        userPerPage:userPerSide
       })
    
    });
    fetch('/api/users/stats/side1/get').then(x=>x.text()).then(Txt=>{
    display.innerHTML=Txt;
    });
});
side2.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    fetch('/api/users/stats/side2/post',{
       method:'POST' ,
       headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},
       body:JSON.stringify({
        pageNum:side2.textContent,
        userPerPage:userPerSide
       })
    
    });  
    fetch('/api/users/stats/side2/get').then(x=>x.text()).then(Txt=>{
        display.innerHTML=Txt;
        });  
});



This is my backend - code:

var retVal; 
app.post('/api/users/stats/side1/post',(req,res)=>{
if(req.body){
const {pageNum,userPerPage}=req.body;
retVal=GetPage(Number(pageNum),Number(userPerPage));
}
});
app.post('/api/users/stats/side2/post',(req,res)=>{
    if(req.body){
    const {pageNum,userPerPage}=req.body;
    retVal=GetPage(Number(pageNum),Number(userPerPage));
    }
});
app.get('/api/users/stats/side1/get',(req,res)=>{
res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/plain');
res.send(retVal);
});
app.get('/api/users/stats/side2/get',(req,res)=>{
res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/plain');
res.send(retVal);
});



I tried different header flags, like explicitly declaring Access-Control-Allow-Origin or no-cors and also async, await on the front-end. The bug occurs independently of the kind of content that gets returned by the server. I tried simplifying the code and changing the POST and GET urls for different html objects to avoid collisions. I was expecting for the fetch requests to be executed, without any sort of blocking. I already did search through the web as well as stackoverflow and while other questions sound familiar to this one, they are about a completely different problem, I think.
What I learned:
The problem does not occur, due to requests taking a bit too much time. And it is not due to Javascript being unable to interact with my server, since the first 5 requests work like expected and then the code breaks. Looking at the network tab, the requests are suddenly pending, so they stop getting through after this point.

Perhaps the problem is that you are not passing the Content-Type and Content-Length header before calling res.send(retVal)

This is not where the problem occurs, it is somewhere in the get/post logic, I just cannot figure out where. Thanks for the input, though. Maybe I will edit the post though, to make apparent, that this is not the issue

Did you check your network tab in the developper tools? To see what the error is about the request?

What is also interesting is that it failed to fetch a HTMl_Div_Element, this refers to the fetch call that POSTS the side1.textContent, but how does it suddenly not retrieve that?? The page also fails to reload at this point. So is there still some blocking going on and how?

Yes I did check the network tab. What happens with the requests is that they are pending. So they somehow stop going through, so there probably is some blocking going on, but I just cannot see where that would be

Well, this is very strange code. Your post prepopulates the get response. Why don't the POST just return the response? You wouldn't have to do two calls. Also, your GET fetch is not waiting for the POST to finish, so retVal could be in a different state than you expect. Also, if there's 2 users on that server they're gonna be able to mess with each other's return values.

If the call stays pending, this could mean there's an error on the server and the client did not receive any answer... I think GetPage is getting slow to process or creates error? You could check the server logs and see if there's something unusal

In addition to what @Salketer has correctly pointed out is wrong with this whole idea, the lack of error handling is #problematic. Depending on the version of node.js, a single bad request could crash your whole server....

The error occurs even if the response would be a constant string. So it is not about how fast GetPage is.

Could you please clarify on how you would wait for an response in the GET fetch request?

@BellFlo to be clear: you have a bunch of problems with your code. It is not worth worrying about the issue you are asking about until you've fixed them, because they may or may not be causing your issue. Use proper state management, proper error handling, proper async task chaining, and if it still doesn't work then come back and update the question/ask a new question.

await fetch(post); await fetch(get); The await keyword will wait for promises to resolve before continuing, and fetch returns a Promise. Btw as they say, is really weird to post data and a get the status in another call. If a post modifies something that should return a status, the post query itself should return the status, so will be atomic in the front-end (and in the back-end it should be properly done and be atomic too. You must read about "atomicity", because you have a bunch of problems here. Trust me, will be good for you to learn about atomicity in the programming world).

I thank everyone for the answers, the problem had been that I did not know, that you could chain a get and a post fetch together, and this then caused all other issues, as well as the reason for my convoluted back-end. I am new to node.js - like the code probably showed you -  and I thank everyone for the effort, and the - for stackoverflow standards - extremely nice and helpful questions

First, I think you could reduce your 4 calls to only one.
app.post('/api/users/stats/post',(req,res)=>{
if(req.body){
const {pageNum,userPerPage}=req.body;
res.send(GetPage(Number(pageNum),Number(userPerPage)));
}else{
// Missing body, say that the input is bad.
res.sendStatus(422);
}
});

This alone is enough.
I have removed the "side1" part as the code is exactly the same as for side2. So let's keep only one route and remove that side thing.
Then, since the POST was used to "pre-configure" the result of the next GET, the GET is completely superfluous since the POST could simply return the result directly. Removing the need for a whole round-trip. At the same time, this completely removes the problem of having to call post before get and making sure that no one else calls post until I call get.
Now, the client had a couple mistakes too. First big one is that it was not waiting for the POST call to finish before calling GET. So it would be possible that the GET would receive the previous value instead of the correct one. But we've got this fixed by using only one POST endpoint.
side1.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    fetch('/api/users/stats/post',{  
       method:'POST',
       headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},
       body:JSON.stringify({
        pageNum:side1.textContent,
        userPerPage:userPerSide
       })
    }).then(x=>x.text()).then(Txt=>{
    display.innerHTML=Txt;
    });
});
side2.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    fetch('/api/users/stats/post',{  
       method:'POST',
       headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},
       body:JSON.stringify({
        pageNum:side2.textContent,
        userPerPage:userPerSide
       })
    }).then(x=>x.text()).then(Txt=>{
    display.innerHTML=Txt;
    });
});

Now this gets a bit less complicated again.
There is other code clean-up that we could do like having the same event listener for both objects etc, but I'm leaving it for now to make the answer clearer.

Just to be clear, this does not fix the OP's issue. But there were some many weird/wrong things going with the code that a clean up is most likely enough to fix it naturally.

alright, so you can wait for the get call by chaining the GET fetch directly to the POST fetch?

To clarify, I was using a GET and a POST statement, because the backend complained, everytime I just used POST , so it seems like the problem was, that I had two seperate statements on the front end then?

The issue with the code was that I had two seperate fetch statements on the front-end.
fetch(post);
fetch(get);

This then forced me to have two different method calls on the backend. What I learned is that for receiving a response to an request from a server, you HAVE to use:
fetch(post).then(...);

Since this tells javascript to wait for the first function to be finished. So my main flaw in understanding was, that:
funcA().funcB(); -> synchronous
funcA();funcB(); -> asynchronous

